# How to Send an attachment with email using MVC webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The attachment size can be maximum up to 1 MB.
Here the client application can be website or windows application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send using WebAPI, you need to do the following in order

1.) Make a post to WebAPI - using Jquery AJAX.

```
type: "POST",         // Type of request to be send, called as method
data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs  
contentType: false,   // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,         // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
```

2.) Make the SMTP call from one of the Helper classes you write in the Business Layer.

If you can share what's there already, we can discuss more on that. If not use the logical steps from above.

Answer (score 0):

Use SmtpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And Attachment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx

The remarks sections show some examples:

```
    public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
    {
        // Specify the file to be attached and sent. 
        // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the 
        // current working directory. 
        string file = "data.xls";
        // Create a message and set up the recipients.
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
           "jane@contoso.com",
           "ben@contoso.com",
           "Quarterly data report.",
           "See the attached spreadsheet.");

        // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
        Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        // Add time stamp information for the file.
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
        // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
        message.Attachments.Add(data);

        //Send the message.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  try {
          client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", 
                ex.ToString() );              
        }
        // Display the values in the ContentDisposition for the attachment.
        ContentDisposition cd = data.ContentDisposition;
        Console.WriteLine("Content disposition");
        Console.WriteLine(cd.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("File {0}", cd.FileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Size {0}", cd.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Creation {0}", cd.CreationDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Modification {0}", cd.ModificationDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Read {0}", cd.ReadDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Inline {0}", cd.Inline);
        Console.WriteLine("Parameters: {0}", cd.Parameters.Count);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry d in cd.Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", d.Key, d.Value);
        }
        data.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: mail sending application is a webapi application

Comment: Yes, you can use SmptClient from a webapi application.  Add a reference to System.Net.Mail

Comment: Suppose the client side application is web how would be send the attachment using the webapi